# Return Wrap of size_t in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, pointers, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp so still blindly finding my way around.  The long and the short of the problem is that I have an object that generates a pointer and I want that pointer returned to R.

I find that casting the pointer to a `size_t` maintains the necessary precision, however, I seem not to be able to return that with `wrap`.

In the code below, only returning the `unsigned long int` will compile, the others throw errors, which for the sake of space I will not include here.  And with my object, casting to an `unsigned long int` causes the compiler to fail due to precision lost (that's in the first block that is all commented out).

Using a `size_t` should suffice for my needs as to avoid the alternative of creating a `wrap` template for this type of object.

I checked the [changelog](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.changelog.html) and it seems that size_t should be supported.  The [overview](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) also suggests `wrap` support for `size_t`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

extern "C" SEXP attempt()
{
    // this block if uncommented gives compile error that converting a pointer to unsigned long int loses precision
    // also, wrapping the pointer &f causes a compilation error
    //int f = 314;
    //unsigned long int theVar_longint = (unsigned long int) &f;
    //cout << "pointer: " << &f << endl;
    //return(wrap(&f));

    // This block makes an arbitrary value into a size_t, unsigned long int and unsigned long long int
    size_t theVar_sizet = (size_t) 383762523;
    unsigned long int theVar_longint = (unsigned long int) 383762523;
    unsigned long long int theVar_longlongint = (unsigned long long int) 383762523;

    // prints the results
    cout << "size_t: " << theVar_sizet << endl;
    cout << "longint: " << theVar_longint << endl;
    cout << "longlongint: " << theVar_longlongint << endl;

    // only the first line returns properly, the others cause errors in compilation
    return(wrap(theVar_longint));
    //return(wrap(theVar_longlongint));
    //return(wrap(theVar_sizet));
}
```

Comment: Did you try R_xlen_t?

Answer (score 1):

What size_t, long int and long long int actually are depend on the platform, so I would advise against relying on them, i.e. wrapping them out to the R side.

We attempted to supprt 64 bit integer types by using the int64 package, but this has caused some issues, which will get fixed. When this is done, you will be able to wrap out either 32 bit integers (int) or 64 bits integers (int64_t). I would discourage using size_t, long or long long.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused: A pointer, by definition, points to a (transient ?) memory location.  Why would you return a pointer to R?

There is one very clearly defined use case, and that involves the R type 'external pointer' (discussed in the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual in [Section 5.13](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#External-pointers-and-weak-references)).  To name a few examples, R's external pointers are used by packages like [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBC) to control the (external) database connection object, by [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) to work with external memory and by my own [RcppDE](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppDE) to hand a compiled objective function down to the differential evolution optimization routine.  All these uses make sense to me---and we have the `Rcpp::XPtr` type to support it---but just passing a pointer around does not.

Can you explain more clearly why you'd need a pointer?

(Also, if you tried to post on rcpp-devel, make sure that your From: address is exactly the same as the address you subscribed with.)

Comment: The post to rcpp-devel was for an entirely different question, but not from the same exact address, I'll resend.

Comment: As for this problem I am trying to build hashing capability based on khash (https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/khash.h).  As far as I can tell it returns a pointer to the memory block where the hash table is stored.  So I thought I could make an R object that pointed to the location and could then access the keys and values in the table.

Comment: No, I fear you can't do that as R can't read random program memory (or at least not in a reliable and portable way, I fear).  What you can do is create a (persistent) class that contains the data and implements the hashing via khash or some other means. You can then provide a 'getter' and a 'setter' to communicate with the class holding the data.

Comment: The 'getter' and 'setter' stuff was part of the plan from the get go.  It's the persistent class that I'll have to brush up on.  I assume that I'll have to expose that class to R using a module?  Thanks.

Comment: No, you can use basic C++; modules is by no means required.  I would try to spec and test something small and simple in C++ only first, then add the getter/setter.  And again, this whole discussion would benefit from exposure to the list.  Can we take it there, please?

Comment: I'm happy to to put it on the list.  I'm going to tackle the C++ only stuff first then get back to the R side at which point I'll send it to the list.